# Can Ubuntu be installed on my system?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, system-installation, ati, uefi

I apologize if this is a duplicated question asked a thousand times, but at the end of 3 days trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 I am close to giving up. I have managed to install it, but I am only able to reach a terminal screen which I am assuming is because of the AMD switchable graphics drivers which I need to install.

I have been trying to follow the answers to these questions:

• [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)
• [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)
• [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

...all of which is to no avail. It would help **if I knew how to connect to my Blink USB internet from within the terminal screen**. Any help would be appreciated.

I find it confusing that the installer is able to run a GUI interface, yet once installed it will not even work in fail safe graphics mode.

• OS: Microsoft Windows 8, Version 6.2.9200 Build 9200
• System Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard, HP Pavilion 15 Notebook PC, x64-based PC
• System SKU: E4X53PA#ABG
• Processor: AMD A6-5200 APU with Radeon(TM) HD Graphics, 2000 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 4   Logical Processor(s)
• Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 8670M, AMD Radeon HD 8400
• BIOS Version/Date: Insyde F.15, 13/06/2013, SMBIOS Version 2.7, Embedded   Controller Version 2.16, UEFI BIOS Mode
• BaseBoard Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard, Platform Role: Mobile
• Secure Boot State: Off
• PCR7 Configuration: Binding Not Possible
• Windows Directory: C:\Windows
• System Directory: C:\Windows\system32
• Boot Device: \Device\HarddiskVolume2
• Hardware Abstraction Layer: Version = "6.2.9200.16442"
• Installed Physical Memory (RAM): 8GB
• Total Physical Memory: 7.47GB
• Available Physical Memory: 5.64GB
• Total Virtual Memory: 8.59GB
• Available Virtual Memory: 6.38GB
• Page File Space: 1.13GB
• Page File: C:\pagefile.sys
• Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
• Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions: Yes
• Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware: No
• Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection: Yes

Answer (score 0):

before  install AMD drives.you must close Dual graphices in bios and remove the system drives. i also have this problem. black screen.

```
sudo apt-get remove fglrx* 
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Comment: bios has no option to close Dual graphics ?

Comment: "sudo apt-get remove fglrx* sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel" is this to remove existing drivers? do i need a connection to the internet during this?

Comment: How do I connect mobile usb broadband via terminal?

Comment: I give up what a shame now have to find a way to live with windows 8 I believe I needed to obtain a internet connection in terminal then I would of been able to install the appropriate graphic drivers. Its not that I have not tried I have been going for four days